# Is there a way to "delay" WM_ACTIVATE / WM_ACTIVATEAPP message?

Tags: c++, winapi

Consider an application with a single window.

If the window is activated - that is if the window procedure (`WindowProc` callback function) receives the message `WM_ACTIVATE` (or alternatively the similar `WM_ACTIVATEAPP`) - it performs an action.
*(The action is to check the opened file for changes; if yes then ask the user if he wants to reload the file)*

The problem: `WM_ACTIVATE`/`WM_ACTIVATEAPP` is also sent when the user performs actions like clicking the close button of the application or moving the window by dragging the titlebar. However those messages are received **before** resulting messages like `WM_CLOSE` or `WM_MOVE` are received. In those cases one obviously wants to wait until the user has finished his action before asking him anything.

Is there a possibility to delay the processing of the `WM_ACTIVATE`/`WM_ACTIVATEAPP` message (which is dispatched when the window is about to be activated) and process other messages (that are dispatched in the process of activating the window) first? The crux is that (if I'm not mistaken) I have no possibility to know *if* another message will be received when initially processing the `WM_ACTIVATE`/`WM_ACTIVATEAPP` message, so how am I supposed to change my behavior depending on what will happen in the future? At the same time I was not able to find another message that would be dispatched *after* the window has been activated (which is essentially what would be needed here).

Comment: `WM_CLOSE` is a special case but it seems silly to break this feature of your app simply because the user moved the window a little bit. You could make the "Do you want to reload the file?" dialog non-modal, that way the user is still free to interact with the main window (and if they close it, you would simply close the dialog).

Comment: Just as a data point, it irritates me beyond measure when applications do this sort of thing.  I'm frequently switching windows for one reason or another, and I don't expect it to have side-effects.

Comment: I agree with @HarryJohnston, from a user experience view, anything you do needs to be non-invasive to be begin with. A model dialog popping up is not acceptable. I will hate your software. Find a more elegant way to do this, such as a non-intrusive overlay, something that doesn't cause a dead-stop in whatever I am doing. Once it's non-intrusive, it immediately solves your entire issue too!

Comment: One possible alternative (for reference) would be to use FindFirstChangeNotification to monitor the file continuously, rather than only checking it when you receive `WM_ACTIVATE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I commented above, I strongly oppose the use of timer here.

There are certain conditions when you do not want to act right away, because client is still performing some action (moving, sizing, etc.). Those action typically require a mouse capture. So my suggestion is:

Post some command message to your window when it gets activated. In case of it being closed, it will never come to processing that command.

When processing that message, check if you are capturing mouse, and if you are - set a flag; check it when you get WM_CAPTURECHANGED message and if it was set - repost the same message to yourself.

Here is the code:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static bool bWaitForCapture = false;
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case WM_APP+1:
            if ((bWaitForCapture = ::GetCapture() == hWnd) != true)
                ::OutputDebugString(L"WM_COMMAND : WM_APP+1\n");
            break;
        case IDM_EXIT:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    case WM_ACTIVATE:
        if (wParam != WA_INACTIVE)
            ::PostMessage(hWnd, WM_COMMAND, WM_APP + 1, 0);
        break;
    case WM_CAPTURECHANGED:
        if (bWaitForCapture)
            ::PostMessage(hWnd, WM_COMMAND, WM_APP + 1, 0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see the potential problems of using a timer and in fact the first part of you answer works really well (using PostMessage once to put the command message to the end of the queue).
However the whole `"bWaitForCapture"` logic seems to be fundamentally broken: It does not perform the action after e.g. moving of the window and is caught in an infinite loop otherwise (constantly receiving `WM_CAPTURECHANGED`) which results in a lot of repainting issues. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: This code works fine for me. the `bWaitForCapture` is static to that WndProc, it is set/reset only when receiving `WM_APP+1` command, depending on if your window is capturing at that time (meaning - dragging or re-sizing). The `WM_CAPTURECHANGED` comes when the capture, naturally changes, and I only re-post that `WM_APP + 1` command if YOU were capturing. Are you by chance testing under debugger, with a breakpoint on `WM_CAPTURECHANGED`? That will be a problem since Debugger will force-break your capture, causing you to re-capture again ans so on.

Comment: At this point I think your code _should_ work in principle and therefore I'll accept it as an answer since it's more elegant than the use of a timer.
However I'm still not able to get it to work since something seems to break as soon as I repost the `WM_ACTIVATE` message in one way or another (same issue with timer) instead of processing it immediately (I open a modal dalog asking the user if he wants to reload but at that point the mouse cursor starts to flicker...).

Comment: Is it a typo, or are you reposting the WM_ACTIVATE message?

Comment: I think we have  over-did it with activation: you get WM_ACTIVATE when you close that modal dialog, getting into a loop. 
It works fine with WM_ACTIVATEAPP instead of WM_ACTIVATE.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that you can delay this message since the message sequence is defined by Windows.

One way to achieve the behaviour you want is to postpone checking for file changes using a timer with some milliseconds delay. This will allow you to check for file updates after it is clear wether the window was activated due to the user wants to edit something or it is being closed. If the delay is short enough the user will not even notice...

The following code snippet shows how to implement this:

```
#define IDT_UPDATE_TIMER   1000


UINT_PTR timerId = NULL;   /* needs to be stored along with other window data */

switch (uMsg)
{
   WM_ACTIVATE:
   WM_ACTIVATEAPP:
      /* create timer to delay checking for file updates... */
      timerId = SetTimer(hWnd, IDT_UPDATE_TIMER, 50, NULL);
      break;

   WM_CLOSE:
      /* cancel timer since window is being closed */
      KillTimer(hWnd, timerId);
      break;

   WM_TIMER:
      switch (wParam)
      {
         case IDT_UPDATE_TIMER:
            /* cancel timer to avoid retesting the file every 50ms */
            KillTimer(hWnd, timerId);

            /* check for file updates... */
            break;
      }
      break;
}
```

Comment: Had to give this an up-vote, looks like we arrived at the same kind of conclusion!

Comment: I strongly oppose the use of timer here: no delay will be enough if I am moving the window slowly, but the long delay, on another hand, will let the user modify the stale content of the file before he gets that popup.

Comment: @VladFeinstein: That's true but I'm using the timer just to postpone checking for file updates until you received further messages and know why your window was activated. So in case you receive a `WM_MOVE` message after a `WM_ACTIVATE` you have to reset (!!! not cancel !!!) the timer. So after you stop moving the window (and don't receive `WM_MOVE` messages anymore) the reset timer expires and the file is checked for updates (in my case 50ms after you stopped moving the window). Same has to be done for `WM_SIZE` and all other messages involving user actions...

Comment: This is flawed fundamentally: your update depends NOT on a time, but on a state. For example, if I grab your (inactive) caption bar and pause, there will be NO messages, MOVE or otherwise, while I am holding. Is this good enough time for you to update? Did you see my proposed solution below?

Answer (score 0):

Good question!

I do not think there's any way to delay the processing of those messages, they logically do appear in the correct sequence - but as your question states, you can't see in to the future.

What you can do, however, is change the way you *handle* these messages, perhaps implementing the use of a timer.  You'll have to imagine a chain of *possible* events.

One way might be to create a class to handle this.  It handles `WM_ACTIVATE`/ `WM_ACTIVATEAPP`.  As soon as it receives this message, start a timer.  If you receive a `WM_MOVE`, handle it, reset the timer.

If you get a `WM_CLOSE` run your activate code, then either call the default window proc or call `DestroyWindow` explicitly.

If the timer expires (half a second?  You might have to play around with the exact threshold), then you can do your activation code.

That's kind of the gist I have in my head and apologies if I have not explained myself very well.

Comment: A timer is a very sloppy solution at best. Maybe, perhaps, the only solution for the messages uses. In that case, I'd very much recommend a non-model dialog kind of solution.